# Binding a List of object to a Chart control

Tags: c#, data-binding, uwp, syncfusion

I am using the SyncFusion UWP library to build an interface with a Chart inside. I followed the [Getting Started](https://help.syncfusion.com/uwp/sfchart/getting-started) example but I can't get it to work. The following code contains some modifications I did to accommodate with my application needs.

**Model**

```
public class Voltage
{
    public DateTime Timestamp;
    public double Value;
}
```

**ViewModel**
I added the notify property changed

```
public class VoltageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public List<Voltage> Data { get; set; }

    public VoltageViewModel()
    {
        Data = new List<Voltage>()
        {
            new Voltage() { Timestamp = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-1), Value = 5.1 },
            new Voltage() { Timestamp = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-2), Value = 4.9 },
            new Voltage() { Timestamp = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-3), Value = 4.85 },
            new Voltage() { Timestamp = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-4), Value = 5.01 }
        };
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        // Raise the PropertyChanged event, passing the name of the property whose value has changed.
        this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<Page
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:ADSO.ViewModel"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:syncfusion="using:Syncfusion.UI.Xaml.Charts"
x:Class="ADSO.MainPage"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

<Page.DataContext>
    <local:VoltageViewModel/>
</Page.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <syncfusion:SfChart HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="20,20,20,20">
        <syncfusion:SfChart.PrimaryAxis>
            <syncfusion:DateTimeAxis Header="Time" Interval="10" IntervalType="Minutes" Minimum="9/22/2018" Maximum="9/23/2018"/>
        </syncfusion:SfChart.PrimaryAxis>
        <syncfusion:SfChart.SecondaryAxis>
            <syncfusion:NumericalAxis Header="Voltage (V)"/>
        </syncfusion:SfChart.SecondaryAxis>
        <syncfusion:LineSeries ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Data}" XBindingPath="Timestamp" YBindingPath="Value" >
        </syncfusion:LineSeries>
    </syncfusion:SfChart>
</Grid>
```

I don't think it's a problem with SyncFusion, and I can confirm that the chart draws successfully but with no data on it. It is a problem with my own implementation but I can't figure out the problem.

Comment: Just a guess: you define `IntervalType="Minutes" Minimum="9/22/2018" Maximum="9/23/2018"` in your XAML, so your X-axis has 1440 points, but your data has only 4 points. Maybe you just can't see them (they are too thin)?

Comment: Thought the same thing and tried to shrink the the interval but nothing as well. Checked the live tree and couldn't see any element drawn in the series canvas

Comment: Another guess: you define `Interval="10" IntervalType="Minutes"` in your XAML, but you data has only 4 points, which may not be in a right time (for ex.: there is labels 12:00 and 12:10, but your point are 12:01, 12:02, 12:03 and 12:04 and so they are not showing)?

Comment: add to the last guess example: there is labels 12:00:00 and 12:10:00, but your point are 12:00:01, 12:01:01, 12:02:01 and 12:03:01 and so they are not showing

Comment: They should appear in the Live Tree even if they are so small, but I'm pretty sure the problem is with the binding not with the points or the axis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the Model instead of the ViewModel.
And make sure that `Timestamp` and `Value` are declared as Properties.

**Model**

```
public class Voltage : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        // Raise the PropertyChanged event, passing the name of the property whose value has changed.
        this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**View Model**

```
public class VoltageViewModel
{
      public List<Voltage> Data { get; set; }

      public VoltageViewModel()
      {
          Data = new List<Voltage>()
          {
              new Voltage() { Timestamp = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-1), Value = 5.1 },
              new Voltage() { Timestamp = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-2), Value = 4.9 },
              new Voltage() { Timestamp = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-3), Value = 4.85 },
              new Voltage() { Timestamp = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-4), Value = 5.01 }
          };
      }

 }
```

Comment: Well yes that was it the main issue was that I missed to define `Timestamp` and `Value` as properties regardless of the `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Thanks!